Apache Superset Deck.gl Multiple Layer Map Filtering
I am having an issue with the Deck.gl Multiple Layer Map in Apache Superset.
I have used a layer as the "Chart Source" and added filter options to the map in the "Filters" panel when creating the map, before adding other Deck.gl charts. However the global filter in the Dashboard does not work with this map.
Is it possible to have the ability to filter one of the layers in the map?
I am looking to create a map with base layers, and only need filtering for the one layer.
Thank you for your help.
